# how to make first column nullable in one to many relationship join table?

Tags: grails, grails3

There seems to be a change in behavior from grails 2 to grails3. When i create a one to many relationship like

```
class Author {
    static hasMany = [books: Book]
    String name
}
class Book {
    String title
}
```

It will create a join table with columns author_books_id and book_id. In grails 3 it also adds a not null constraint on the first column. In grails 2 not null constraint is not applied. So when i upgrade to grails 3 it is breaking because there are already few records that have first column values to null. It works fine in grails 2 but with grails 3 the first column should not be null. Furthermore the join table is read only so i cannot remove the rows will null first column values. Is there a way to make the first column nullable = true by making changes in domains and not directly in migration file.

The code was extracted from the grails documentation. Please scroll down to one to many section.

6.2.1.2 One-to-many

http://docs.grails.org/3.0.17/guide/GORM.html

Comment: I'm not sure why a row exists in a join table that doesn't join 2 things together... the rows in your join table with a null on one side seem useless, and should be removed.   That said... you don't have to let grails create your tables, and you CAN modify those tables once they're created, if you need to remove that constraint, you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your Book class to this

```
class Book {
    String title
    Author author     // this creates the belongs to relationship
}

static constraints = {
     author nullable:true
}
```

Also when you recompile the code make sure to delete previous table and start fresh. Grails will not alter any table to delete anythings. It only adds new stuffs.